# How to display data on the same page when querying a different page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a file named as 'display.php', which contains this code:

```
    <a href="./codetemplate.php?id=Name>Click here</a>
```

Then in my code file, it will fetch the data and display it, BUT...

How do I show the data that is displayed on 'codetemplate.php' in the 'display.php' page?

In other words, take data from some page and display it on another one.

Ideally, I don't want the `a` to have any parameters when you hover over it. I want it to have a variable like so:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleAppearance(\''.$row['Name'] .'\');">'.$row['Name'] .'</a>
```

It will be contained in a while loop, but then the hard part is displaying the data based on the value of a link.

eg:

```
Bob
george
Sara
John
```

4 names in the database that were found and displayed as anchor links.

If you click on Bob, a div will be displayed showing all of the data in the database that pertains to Bob. Click on Sara, it will show all the data for Sara and so on.

I'm not sure what the best method to try is. Using onclick with row or using a file name, which will query the data in another file.

Comment: onclick with row is good way.If you want more data then "fetch data" to another page with "id" is best way.

Comment: All you need is to use Ajax. it will solve all your problem. If you mention your proper code then we can help you more specifically

Answer (score 0):

I would personally query all the data in your display.php file. If people are going to hover over the names, they might as well hover over all the names. So I guess it would be beneficial to query is all on the same page.

But to answer your question: You can use an ajax request to get all the data and display it on your display.php like so:

example:

```
<input type="text" id="text1"> +
<input type="text" id="text2">
<button id="button"> = </button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And the javascript (using jquery)

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var val1 = $('#text1').val();
   var val2 = $('#text2').val();
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'websiteToFetchDataFrom.php',
      data: { text1: val1, text2: val2 },
      success: function(response) {
         $('#result').html(response);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: but how would you write the jquery if it's <a href> not an <input> or <button>?